# Is there a way to prevent a [Column] from rebuilding when the height of a child changes?

Tags: flutter, height

Is there a way to prevent a `Column` from rebuilding when the height of one of its children changes?

The column should not be rebuilt when `SizeTransition`'s animation is played.

```
Column(
  children: [
    SizeTransition(
      // Multiple arguments.
      child: DynamicSizeWidget_A(),
    ),
    DynamicSizeWidget_B(),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Share some code snippets. That helps to answer.

Comment: you can give both children to fix side or fix size to Column(wrap with Sizedbox)

Comment: I have edited my question to make clear that the sizes of some widgets are not fixed. Thank you for your participation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use setState to change the height of a child then your entire build method will be rebuilt. but if you use state management package like provider or riverpod, then you can wrap your child with `Consumer Widget`, and only your child will be rebuilt.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you. Thank you for your contribution!